# SQLite vs Couchbase Lite for Xamarin app

Tags: sqlite, couchbase-lite

Our company is creating an enterprise app using Xamarin that will be deployed on Windows 10, iOS, and Android devices.

Our developers only have experience with relational databases and we like the more structured nature of SQL, so our plan is to go with SQLite. Are there any reasons we should consider Couchbase Lite instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very subjective question and here are some subjective reasons why you might consider it:

- Couchbase Mobile allows you to use Sync Gateway to sync data from the device to other devices (and to a Couchbase Server if you want)
- You don't have to worry as much about your schema changing between versions of your app
- It's easier to store complex hierarchy (i.e. you don't have to use multiple tables and foreign keys as much)

For more p̶r̶o̶p̶a̶g̶a̶n̶d̶a̶ information, check out the [Couchbase Mobile Developer Portal](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile).

Comment: That lines up with what I've read, thanks for the answer. We already have a sync process built and have a simple db so will probably stick with SQLite. Thanks!